# Which is the best dotnet core librery for controlling servo on Raspberry pi 4

Tags: pi-4, windows-iot, servo

Hello all I am doing research on the best library for controling servo motor on `Rapberi pi 4` using C#.
I tried some old ones. I will be grateful if you direct me to the best one for the purpose.

Comment: Did you find out what was wrong with the servos?

Comment: No man. I continued the tests with the old code But I'm still checking for the best solution. I changed the operating system from arm32 to arm64 and the previous code stopped working .